# How to check date of birthday for validity?

Tags: java

I receive a string with a date in format: 1990-05-30

1. I need to convert it to LocalDate
2. Check that is valid to year/month-day like in my example
3. And return true or false.

Can you show a good practice?

```
public boolean check(String date){
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Do your homework. SO is not a place where we do your homework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. All you need to do now is :

```
public boolean check(String date){
    try {
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date);
        return true; // valid date if parsing was successful
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false; // not a valid date
    }
}
```